# Handling self-signed certificate errors when using chrome.sockets.tcp.secure

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am using [chrome.sockets.tcp API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp#method-secure) to create a secure connection. No errors are being encountered when connecting using a trusted certificate.

However, I'm facing error -202 (CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID) (among other possible [certificate errors][2]) when trying to connect to a server with a self-signed/untrusted certificate.

Is it possible to warn the user about the invalid certificate and provide the option to continue with the connection? (similar to the way Chrome handles such situations)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing nothing on the topic in the docs (and `SocketsTcpSecureFunction::AsyncWorkStart()`, the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/browser/api/sockets_tcp/sockets_tcp_api.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=520&rcl=1445874174) of `chrome.sockets.tcp.secure`, only verifies the certificate but doesn't try to handle the errors, it would only report them back) I'd conclude there's no way to interactively handle this predicament.

Maybe you can import the certificate on the client machine but it won't help other users of the site unless they're willing to do the same.